# Android: How to add shadow-effect to this Vector

Tags: android

I am using following XML as background to a Button in my app.

Can anyone guide me how to add 3D-effect(shadow) to it

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:pathData="M5.7,12.5l-5.7,11.5 12,0 12,0 -5.7,-11.5c-3.2,-6.3 -6,-11.5 -6.3,-11.5 -0.3,0 -3.1,5.2 -6.3,11.5z"
        android:strokeColor="#00000000"
        android:fillColor="#5F9999"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: Don't do that. It will add too many data to your XML file. Check it here: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html#when

Answer (score 1):

here is a sample of gradient that you can experiment with to give the style or 3D effect .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_focused="true">
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="0dip" />
         <stroke android:width="0dip" android:color="#cb1307" />
         <solid  android:color="#cb1307"/>       
     </shape>
 </item>  
<item >
    <shape  android:shape="rectangle" >
         <corners android:radius="10dip" />
         <gradient  android:angle="270"  android:startColor="#fff" android:endColor="#89F5D7" />            
     </shape>
 </item>
```

Comment: I have this. I wanted to know how to add this to a vector from the XML that I posted.

Thank you for your response.

Comment: just add to background   android:background="@drawable/abv.xml"

Comment: I have a Button that uses the XML i posted as its background. 
I am not sure where to apply `android:background="@drawable/abv.xml"`

Can you explain please.

Comment: Hi , you can use background only once , abc.xml is just an example you can use your above file as background , but you have to edit your background.xml (say)  and add gradient to it. it will work for you